# Connecting to an EKS cluster without CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm trying to connect to the EKS cluster I created using Python's kubernetes library, and leveraging session tokens for authentification, but it doesn't seem to be going through, I keep getting Unauthorized 401 response at the last line.

Here's the code that I'm using.

```py
sts_client = boto3.client('sts', aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key=KEY_SECRET)

response = sts_client.assume_role(
    RoleArn=ROLE_ARN,
    RoleSessionName='AssumeRoleSession'
)

credentials = response['Credentials']

eks = boto3.client(
    'eks', 
    region_name = REGION, 
    aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'], 
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken']
    )


cluster_data = eks.describe_cluster(name=CLUSTER_NAME)['cluster']

config = client.Configuration()
config.host = f"{cluster_data['endpoint']}"
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as cert:
    cert.write(base64.b64decode(cluster_data['certificateAuthority']['data']))
    config.ssl_ca_cert = cert.name
config.api_key={'authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials['SessionToken']}

apiclient = client.ApiClient(configuration=config)
v1_client = client.CoreV1Api(api_client=apiclient)
v1_client.list_namespace()
```

The role in question has all EKS actions allowed, and there is a trust relationship established between them, cluster_data looks properly populated.

Is the session token not enough, and if so is it even possible to authenticate without relying on the underlying OS?